Different Values for SSIZE_MAX Between limits.h, getconf/sysconf on Linux
I'm encountering an issue on my 64-bit Linux machine where both the getconf command and the sysconf() function report the value of SSIZE_MAX as 32767, which is the minimum value required by POSIX. However, this seems unusually low for a 64-bit system. In contrast, the SSIZE_MAX defined in limits.h is 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, which aligns more with what I would expect for a 64-bit platform. Can anyone explain why there is such a significant difference in the reported values of SSIZE_MAX?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>  // For SSIZE_MAX
#include <unistd.h>  // For sysconf

int main() {
    // Print the SSIZE_MAX from limits.h
    printf("SSIZE_MAX from limits.h: %zd\n", SSIZE_MAX);
    
    // Get and print the SSIZE_MAX from sysconf
    long sysconf_value = sysconf(_SC_SSIZE_MAX);
    if (sysconf_value == -1) {
        printf("Failed to get SSIZE_MAX from sysconf");
    } else {
        printf("SSIZE_MAX from sysconf: %ld\n", sysconf_value);
    }

    return 0;
}

Here there are the numbers:
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
SSIZE_MAX from limits.h: 9223372036854775807
SSIZE_MAX from sysconf: 32767

$ getconf SSIZE_MAX
32767

GNU documents says the following for sysconf() 1:

We recommend that you first test for a macro definition for the parameter you are interested in, and call sysconf only if the macro is not defined

Can we conclude that if SSIZE_MAX is already defined, using sysconf() to retrieve its value might yield incorrect results? Or is the recommendation to avoid using sysconf() simply to eliminate unnecessary function calls, implying that if the macro is defined, its value should be used directly since both sources should theoretically provide the same value?
Edit: It looks like glibc returns _POSIX_SSIZE_MAX with sysconf(_SC_SSIZE_MAX) 2:
//
case _SC_SSIZE_MAX:
  return _POSIX_SSIZE_MAX;
//


Note that _SC_SSIZE_MAX is a glibc-specific configuration, it's not part of POSIX.

Some programmer dude reported that _SC_SSIZE_MAX is a glibc-specific configuration, and not part of POSIX.
For glibc,

getconf SSIZE_MAX calls sysconf( _SC_SSIZE_MAX ).
sysconf( _SC_SSIZE_MAX ) returns _POSIX_SSIZE_MAX (not SSIZE_MAX).
_POSIX_SSIZE_MAX is fixed at 32767.

In other words, it reports on POSIX's thoughts about SSIZE_MAX, and POSIX only speaks of its minimum.

Thank you! Any rationale behind glibc's this choice? Can I trust and use the value of SSIZE_MAX in limits.h?

@ayazar, Yes, limits provides the actual limits.
